# php Array output in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

My array is 
`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [book_title] => Brief History of Time: From Big Bang to Black Hole [pd_id] => p22670689244706 [price] => 499.00 [author] => Stephen W. Hawking [book_type] => pb [status] => Pending ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [book_title] => The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4A [pd_id] => p23662839087202 [price] => 899.00 [author] => Donald E. Knuth [book_type] => pb [status] => Pending ) ) )`

How can I print `book_title`, price, `book_type` in view page in codeigniter?

Comment: create new view and add it in controller that will be sufficient to show your array in view. Check my answer below, with full description

Comment: look at tihs http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html, please do not post questions , with out searching it :(, there are many examples around . just type "view codeigniter" in google

Answer (score 1):

Given your array is called `$array`, you can do like this:

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
   foreach ($arr as $ar) {
      echo $ar['book_title'];
      echo $ar['price'];
      echo $ar['book_type'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use foreach loop twice to get the values...

try this...

```
foreach ($arrayName as $result){ // first loop gets all the value inside first array  
    foreach($result as $row){   //second gets the value inside the first array..
        echo $row['book_title'];
        echo $row['price'];
        echo $row['book_type'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create view "listing.php" in your **application/views** folder add this code in it

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Book listing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    foreach ($books as $book) {           
     echo $book['book_title'] .' -- ' . $book['price'] .' -- ' . $book['book_type']. '<br>';
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

In your **controller** function write code like this

```
$data['books'] = $yourArray; //@todo : replace your array name with $yourArray
$this->load->view('listing', $data);
```